# JSP inside script tag | Find the URL of the file in which it is included

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have an html page (http://www.somedomain.com/index.html) which has contents like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="proxy.jsp"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a JSP(proxy.jsp) that is included in this page within the script tag.

Now inside my JSP (proxy.jsp) I would like to know the URL of the page in which this JSP is included inside a script tag which in this case is http://www.somedomain.com/index.html

Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I used request.getHeader("referer"); in proxy.jsp which gave me the url http://www.somedomain.com/index.html.